# nodejs - cache data into an object or array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to cache some informations in a node CLI script using an array or an object. I want to have a simple key value that I can ckeck to get usernames using the id that I want to use as the key. I'm trying with this code but I'm not sure if it will work as expected

```
let threads = [];
ig.realtime.on('message', async (data) => { 
    if( String(data.message.user_id) === ig.state.cookieUserId ){
        return;
    } else if ( data.message.path.endsWith('has_seen') ){
        return;
    } else if( !threads.includes(data.message.thread_id) ){
        const thread = await ig.feed.directThread({thread_id: data.message.thread_id}).request();
        threads[thread.thread.thread_id] = {
            username: thread.thread.users[0].full_name,
        }
    } 
});
```

Will the `threads[thread.thread.thread_id]` add the id as key each time that it will not be found into the array or I need to use `Array.push()` function?

Can I access to the key of the array in this way `threads[data.message.thread_id]` to get the related value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
if(!threads.find(o=>o.id==id)){
    threads.push({id, ...})
}
```

or simply use Map()  as bellow

```
let threads = new Map();

if(!threads.has(id)){
   threads.set(id, value)
}
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using map instead of a traditional object?

Comment: easy to loop / search /  delete, maybe this link can define something to u https://codeburst.io/array-vs-set-vs-map-vs-object-real-time-use-cases-in-javascript-es6-47ee3295329b

Comment: The `set()` Take a key and a value right? I can access to the values using this way `threads[data.message.thread_id]`? Thank you for the help

Comment: use threads.get(id), see this doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: I'm reading the articles ypuv'e linked, very useful. If I've understand the `new Map()` will add new key value pair on each call of `set()`, right? Thanks for clarifications and help, I'm implementing it in my code!